# I'm trying to pass a $_SESSION var

Tags: php, html, session, session-variables

Why does this not work? Where is my mistake, I'm trying to pass a `$_SESSION` var, to another site:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Buch eintragen</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <table><form method='post'>
        <tr><td>ISBN: </td><td><input type='text' name='isbn' /></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Titel: </td><td><input type='text' name='title' /></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Autor: </td><td><input type='text' name='autor' /></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Verlag: </td><td><input type='text' name='verlag' /></td></tr>
        <tr><td><input type='submit' value='neues Buch anlegen'/></td></tr>
        </form></table>
        <?php 
        session_start();
        if (isset($_POST['isbn'])){
        $_SESSION['isbn'] = $_POST['isbn'];
        $_SESSION['title'] = $_POST['title'];
        $_SESSION['autor'] = $_POST['autor'];
        $_SESSION['verlag'] = $_POST['verlag'];

        //header('Location: /KlausurSchulzke/buch-eintragen.php');
        } ?>

        <strong><?php echo $_SESSION['isbn'];?></strong>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Do you successfully enter the if statement?

Comment: even this is not working, without the if statement

Comment: What is your code in this file `/KlausurSchulzke/buch-eintragen.php` ? do you get any errors? We honestly do not fully know what is wrong besides you saying it "does not work"

Comment: plz clear what  error do u getting

Comment: plz read my answer, I will @home

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks for all of your effort.
I found/remeber a simple workaround.
I know, it´s not the real answer to my question, but Im runnig out of time. And my teacher also prohibited me to use php in my html-file.

HTML-File

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Buch eintragen</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <table><form method='post' action="buch-eintragen.php">
        <tr><td>ISBN: </td><td><input type='text' name='isbn' /></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Titel: </td><td><input type='text' name='title' /></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Autor: </td><td><input type='text' name='autor' /></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Verlag: </td><td><input type='text' name='verlag' /></td></tr>
        <tr><td><input type='submit' value='neues Buch anlegen'/></td></tr>
        </form></table>
        <div class='button menu' onclick="javascript:location.href='/KlausurSchulzke/SchulzkeKlausurBuecherSQL.php'">Menu</div>
</body>

</html>
```

PHP-File

```
<?php
$baseURI = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
        openSQL();
        $sqlbefehl = 'INSERT INTO `buecher` VALUES (\''.$_POST['isbn'].'\',\''.$_POST['title'].'\',\''.$_POST['autor'].'\',\''.$_POST['verlag'].'\')';
        @mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
        @mysql_query($sqlbefehl);
        header('Location: /KlausurSchulzke/SchulzkeKlausurBuecherSQL.php?command=work');

function openSQL()
{
    $server   = "localhost";
    $user     = "root";
    $passwort = "";
    $db       = "schulzke";
    $dblink   = @mysql_connect($server, $user, $passwort);
    if (!@mysql_select_db($db)) {
        echo "<br>Keine Verbindung zur Datenbank $db möglich!";
        echo "<br>" . mysql_error();
        global $baseURI;
        echo "<div class='button menu' onclick=\"javascript:location.href='$baseURI'\">Menu</div>";
        die();
    }

}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

session_start() needs to be at the top of the page before any headers are sent.

You must put at the top of your file that you want a session on:

```
<?php
session_start(); // session is always at the top here.
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Buch eintragen</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <table><form method='post'>
        <tr><td>ISBN: </td><td><input type='text' name='isbn' /></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Titel: </td><td><input type='text' name='title' /></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Autor: </td><td><input type='text' name='autor' /></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Verlag: </td><td><input type='text' name='verlag' /></td></tr>
        <tr><td><input type='submit' value='neues Buch anlegen'/></td></tr>
        </form></table>
        <?php 
        if (isset($_POST['isbn'])){
        $_SESSION['isbn'] = $_POST['isbn'];
        $_SESSION['title'] = $_POST['title'];
        $_SESSION['autor'] = $_POST['autor'];
        $_SESSION['verlag'] = $_POST['verlag'];

        //header('Location: /KlausurSchulzke/buch-eintragen.php');
        } ?>

        <strong><?php echo $_SESSION['isbn'];?></strong>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: this also don´t work
is it maybe this? http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php
because my php is outcommented with ´<!-- php-code -->´

Comment: PHP code cannot be commented out like that.  Where do you have `<!-- php-code -->`?  Please edit your original post to include any missing code, thank you

Comment: it is only in the browser-inspector, this is my code

Comment: What is the browser inspector? Post the code from `/KlausurSchulzke/buch-eintragen.php`

Comment: when I watch the generated DOM in the browser, then my php is outcommented 
I posted the ´/KlausurSchulzke/buch.html´
the jump with ´//header('Location: /KlausurSchulzke/buch-eintragen.php');´ is not needed atm

Comment: you need to rename buch.html to buch.php, HTML files cannot run PHP code unless you edit a server setting.

Comment: A struggle I faced before: if the file contains a BOM, the session_start(); is not on top anymore. It is visually, but it's not for the browser. You can check it out with Notepad++